# How can one do if/else statements in VB/.NET for a page name?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

This is the first time I've touched .net and coming from PHP things look familiar but not sure how do go about this.

code:

```
If [your condition here]
    Your code here
Else
    Your code Here
End If
```

For the above code I want to do something like this:

```
    if current page = default.aspx then include 
    <%=HttpHelper.ExecutePage("/UserControls/somefile.aspx")%>

Else if it isn't then don't show it.
```

How can I do this in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that

```
  Dim CurrentPath As String = Request.Url.AbsolutePath
  Dim TargetPath As String = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/default.aspx")

  If CurrentPath.ToLower = TargetPath.ToLower Then
            Server.Execute("~/UserControls/somefile.aspx")
  End If
```